# Why my events from iOS app doesnt displayed in Google Analytics page?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm init GA with this code from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 5;
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GA_TRACKING_ID];
```

after that, im trying to send event:

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] trackEventWithCategory:@"Category" withAction:@"Action" withLabel:@"Label" withValue:@1];
```

but without any result.

BTW

```
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] trackView:@"TEST VIEW"];
```

works perfectly, and i see it on my GA page.
What im doing wrong with events?

Comment: Do you know where Events results listed at Google Analytics page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trackView` & `trackEventWithCategory` are deprecated.

Give `sendEventWithCategory` a try.

edit: are you using the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: I'm using Google Analytics iOS SDK version 2.0 Beta 4 and already try track and send versions of methods with same result.

Comment: And you are aware, that you don't see realtime data? You can view 'some' realtime data, but Events is not one of them.

Comment: I see on Realtime page sendView's, but don't see on Engagement->Events any my sent events.

Comment: Thank you, today all events properly displayed.